# Combine PullToRefresh library with ListViewAnimations library

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I'm using https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations to animate my listview and to implement some drag & drop functionality to my list items.

Now, I need to use Cris Banes's Android-PullToRefresh https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh library **in the same listview** to add more items. (Yes, I know that is deprecated and there's a new version, but this is the only one which allows to pull from the bottom of the list).

My question is if there's some way to combine both libraries or some workaround to implement both functionality to my listview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "but this is the only one which allows to pull from the bottom of the list" what do you mean?

Comment: @MartínMarconcini I mean that Cris Banes has to libraries that allows you to implement pull-to-refresh in listview. The newest one is called ActionBar-PullToRefresh [link](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh), which implements the pull-to-refresh like Gmail way. But this, just allows to pull from the top of the list and not from the bottom. (That's my case and because of I'm using the old one).

Comment: I know about Chris' New library, I just don't fully understand what a pull from the bottom of the list is… you mean pulling UP?

Comment: @MartínMarconcini Yes, I mean pulling up.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry, I've never used the old library and I think you'd be better by using the new one and adding the pull capability, the old one is very hacky.

Comment: May I ask why do you need pull to refresh from the bottom? Seems very unintuitive to me (from a UX point of view).

Comment: @MartínMarconcini The purpose of this is to add more elements to the bottom of listview. And because list's elements are based on time, the new elements will be placed after those.